# Can anyone explain this PHP?

Tags: php, html, dynamic

```
<ul class="top_ads">
    <?php
        $totalImages = 5;
        $all = range(1,$totalImages);
        shuffle($all);

        foreach ($all as $single) {
            echo "<li><a href='' /><img src='"; echo bloginfo('template_url') . "/images/ads/ad_0$single.png' alt='ad' /></li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

can anyone please explain bloginfo('template_url') within this php code? sorry, if it seems trivial to you. also the path "/images/ads/ad_0$single.png". I am learning php. Thank you.

Which function I need to use in place of bloginfo('template_url') if I do not use wordpress but php as a template engine? anyone helps me?

Comment: It's a wordpress function. This is what google told me... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

Comment: `bloginfo()` is a function and `$single` is a variable containing number from (1 to 5)

Answer (score 1):

the function is randomizing 5 ads.
each ad has the name in:
/images/ads/ad_01.png .. /images/ads/ad_05.png.

first the range (1, 5) makes an array {1,2,3,4,5}
shuffle mixes it up so it looks more like {4,3,5,1,2}
foreach ($all as $single) will call the echo statement for each of those numbers in the new order

bloginfo('template_url') is a function somewhere else in your code. it is outputting a template url path partial.  most likely its something like /templates.

using chrome: you can figure that out by right clicking on one of these ads and choosing inspect element and find the exact url that is being built out.

Comment: Which function I need to use in place of bloginfo('template_url') if I do not use wordpress but php as a template engine? anyone helps me?

Comment: PHP is not a template engine.

Comment: bloginfo('template_url') is just outputting a fragment of the url.  once you know where the ads images live, just hard code that path instead of making the call.